# Problem with resistance,electric circuit etc. etc.

Tags: voltage, power, dc, resistance

In which way a resistance is to be connected with a bulb labelled 120W-60V when it is connected with 220V DC source so that maximum illumination with proper security is maintained? What is the necessary amount of resistance needed? If I connect it in parallel connection then proper security is maintained but not maximum illumination.On the contrary, series connection cause damage to the bulb though high illumination is obtained. Is there a way to verify and analyse mathematically? Am I right? If yes then how will I calculate the resistance?

Comment: someone there?please help me with this thing. I don't have a clear concept on this. Some people say series, some says parallel. Or they give the necessity of using a shunt.

Comment: Is it a normal 'incandescent' bulb a fluorescent or LED?

Comment: @Icy normal bulb

Comment: Please define 'security'. Please define what you mean by 'series' and 'parallel', because if they mean the same to you as they mean to me, it shows a deeper level of misunderstand on your part. Perhaps edit your post to include a circuit diagram of a lamp in series or parallel with a resistor, in fact doing this exercise might solve your problem for you by the teddy-bear effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 120W 60V normal incandescent bulb behave like a resistor. So it requires 2A to operate (120W = 60V * 2A). To make this work from 220V you need to drop 160V (220V-60V) across a *series* resistor. To get this voltage drop you need a resistor of 80 Ohms (160V/2A) - BUT this resistor will need to be capable of dissipating 320W (160V * 2A)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLSNco.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A possible way to do this is to wire 4 of these bulbs in series (each would be slightly dimmer than optimal).

Comment: Why won't we connect it in parallel ? What problems would have raised if we connected the resistance in parallel?

Comment: +1 for the 4 bulb in series but you could also replace it with 4 bulbs of 30W each and save the power that would have been wasted in the load resistor.

Comment: @Tagore connection in parallel would just blow 4 60V bulbs across the 220V mains instead of just one.  In series each bulb will have 55V to work with and if they are matched bulbs will have a long lifetime

Comment: @Tagore You would still have 220V across the bulb - therefore it would draw 220V/30R = 7.3A  - *or 1613 Watts !* - and have a very short but bright life ! (assuming the 220V source is not current limited in some way)

Comment: @KalleMP But I wanted maximum illumination from the bulb but with proper security.

Comment: Get a bulb rated at 220-240V !

Comment: ok .I got it. ..

Comment: @Tagore You will then have to go shopping for a 220V to 60V transformer or a 60V switched mode powersupply.  I expect there are COTS products out there but may be more than consumer priced as I cannot think of consumer applications.  Projection lamps may have similar needs and would be where I would go shopping for power systems.

Comment: @Tagore As an extra note if you are using a halogen type bulb (which seems possible with your brightness desires) it should be driven at pretty close to the rated voltage (5% deviation usually best) or it will suffer faster failure. Bulb blackening at low voltages and filament erosion at high voltages.

Answer (score 3):

I have used some capacitive power sources for low voltage applications and why one couldn't be used for this one? Since an ideal capacitor is a reactive element, it wouldn't dissipate any active power (more economical and cooler (temperature wise)) 
You could try connecting a capacitor with a value of about 40 uF (as found in fluorescent light bulb starters) with a 500k to 1M bleeder resistor in series with the bulb.

These caps can get quite expensive, but net more expensive as 300 Watt resistor :D

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frY39S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>